# Is there a way to use ScanQuery against interface of cache values?

Tags: ignite

We run 2-node Ignite cluster with persistence and peer class loading enabled. We’ve faced a peer class loading issue that can be reduced to this:

`IgniteCache` stores values of classes A, B, C. All they implement same interface X. Any `ScanQuery` for that cache that tries to operate on interface X like

```
 val cache: IgniteCache<UUID, X> 
.....
 val query = ScanQuery<UUID, X> { _, entry ->  .... }
 cache.query(query, { it.key }).use { keys ->
            for (key in keys) {
                 ........
```

fails with :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to X

    at ….Scheduler$poll$dueQuery$1.apply(Scheduler:61)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.advance(GridCacheQueryManager.java:3089)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.onHasNext(GridCacheQueryManager.java:2982)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)

at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.runQuery(GridCacheQueryManager.java:1164)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryRequest(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:230)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:108)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:106)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1054)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:579)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:378)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:304)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:99)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:293)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1556)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1184)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:125)

    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1091)

    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

If we only keep a single specific class `A` in that cache and let `ScanQuery` operate on that cache, everything works fine.

A,B,C classes are marshaled by OptimizedMarshaller because of custom serialization with Externalizable.

Is this scenario supported? Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the classloader of `X`? What's `a.getClass().getClassLoader()`?

Comment: it's same for both - org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@182decdb

Comment: It's very strange in this case. Why can't be A cast to X?